# There's is a way of getting just an exe/linux binary/app file from NeutralinoJS?

Tags: neutralinojs

I'm trying to make a simple application with [neutralinoJS](https://github.com/neutralinojs/neutralinojs)

I'm wondering how get a unique file:

- .exe to windows
- a binary, .deb, .rpm to linux
- and a .app to macOS

Cause there is a file that runs the html/js but the source code is visible to edit

[Files are visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVKhl.png)

Answer (score 1):

Neutralinojs produces portable cross platform apps. Therefore, your application files (css, js etc) and Neutralino framework files (settings.json etc) are visible from application bundle.

Whereas, they are having an idea to make a [packager tool](https://github.com/neutralinojs/neutralinojs/issues/127) which will minify app source.

Hope it helps